# How do I attach event to popup parent's parent?

Tags: javascript

I want to attach an event to popup parent's parent.

Hierarchy is like this:-

Form1(master page) containing iframe opens Form2(without master page) opens a popup.

I want to identify Form1 in popup opened by Form2 through Javascript.How do I do it?

It works only for Form2.

```
window.opener.document.attachEvent("onclick",setfocus);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me

```
window.top.opener.window.top.document.getElementById("contentIFrame").document.attachEvent("onclick",setfocus);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if all are on the [same hostname, protocol, and port number](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_DOM_access), and if the windows have not been closed:

```
// if you're opening Form2 from outside the iframe
window.opener.opener.document.attachEvent("onclick",setfocus); 

// if you're opening Form2 from inside the iframe
window.opener.opener.parent.document.attachEvent("onclick",setfocus);
```

Note that `attachEvent` is IE/Opera only, so if you expect this to work cross-browser, consider [using `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for those other browsers.

I would also seriously reconsider opening numerous pop-up windows, opening pop-ups from those pop-ups, *etc.* For at least publicly accessible web applications, pop-up blockers would be a big enough problem alone.

Comment: I am opening Form2 in iframe.I am getting following error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'window.opener.opener.parent' is null or not an object